# Recognizing duplicate values and adding them an extension automatically

Tags: microsoft-excel, duplicate, extension

I need a formula or a macro for Excel to do the next operations:
Identify the duplicates and leaving the first value as it is for example

```
2
2
2
2
2
2
```

Should become

```
2
2.1
2.2
2.3
2.4
2.5
```

This should be done to all duplicates in a specific column, in this case being the column B.

What I tried until now was using a formula like

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:$B$5000,B1)>1,B1& " (" & COUNTIF(B$1:B1,B1) & ")",B1)
```

Which didn't work and in case of programming a macro in VB isn't really my strong suite. The macro that I tested is also not working:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim dataRng As Range
Dim dataArr() As Variant, output() As String
Dim y As Long, i As Long, j As Long, tmpcount As Long
Set dataRng = Range("B1").Resize(Me.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1)
If Not Intersect(Target, dataRng) Is Nothing Then
    dataArr = dataRng.Value
    ReDim output(1 To UBound(dataArr, 1), 1 To 1)
   For y = 1 To UBound(dataArr, 1)
        If Right(dataArr(y, 1), 1) = ")" Then
            dataArr(y, 1) = Left(dataArr(y, 1), InStr(dataArr(y, 1), " (") - 1)
        End If
    Next y
    For i = 1 To UBound(dataArr, 1)
        tmpcount = 0
        output(i, 1) = dataArr(i, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(dataArr, 1)
            If dataArr(i, 1) = dataArr(j, 1) Then
                tmpcount = tmpcount + 1
                If j = i And tmpcount > 1 Then
                    output(i, 1) = dataArr(i, 1) & " (" & tmpcount & ")"
                    Exit For
                End If
                If j > i And tmpcount > 1 Then
                    output(i, 1) = dataArr(i, 1) & " (" & tmpcount - 1 & ")"
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Call printoutput(output, dataRng)
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub printoutput(what As Variant, where As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
where.Value = what
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Does anybody have an idea of what is to be done here?
Thank you in advance for your responses.

Comment: More info is needed here. For starters, are we talking about excel?

Comment: Sorry, yes we are talking about Excel

Comment: in that case, you should add this to the question

Comment: I did it now :)

Comment: You should also add what you try as your question reads like "do my work for me" :(

Comment: Sorry, I'm new at this, I will

Comment: Daniel, +1 from me! This is now a great question. In your example, you only show lots of 2, but, after 2 is there ever a 3? I mean, if you have 2, then type in 2.1 in the next row, and then 2.2 in the next row, you can then drag this down and Excel will populate it for you

Comment: That was just an example, I have probably more then 5000 cells to check for duplicates and perform this action for each, whereas the excel that I receive is being updated every 15 minutes. The values that I have are more along the line of 63539 or 85451 which appear more than once (duplicates). I don't want to get rid of the duplicates, because these are also very important, all I need is to be able to add that .1, .2..... and so on extension to each duplicate found, leaving the first found value as it is

Answer (score 3):

With values in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=A1
```

and in **B2** enter:

```
=A2 & IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A2)=0,"","." & COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A2))
```

and copy down:

[image]

*Note*:  There is no requirement to have the values in column **A** sorted.

Comment: I received an error message using this formula. How can I also send a print screen as a comment?

Comment: This is what came out http://de.tinypic.com/r/mja83/9

Comment: @Daniel  **Make sure your formula is consistent with your Local Language Settings.**

Comment: What are your setting, because I've changed mine and it still is not working

Comment: I've tried to switch to language English (US) and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the response to see the cause of the error (I could not open your link de.tinypic.com/r/mja83/9  to see what is happening).
For example write =countif($A$1:A1,A2) in C2 try using fx or insert Formula to use the corresponding one in your language and maybe the list separator is ; not , in your computer settings.
Also for =If(C2=0,"",",") in D2
Then in B2=A2 & D2 & C2
If everything is right combine the formulas again.
Gary's Formula is right and works